# Power Pivot Security

Tags: excel, powerpivot

I've made a Pivot Table with Power Pivot analysis in excel 2010 and I am about to publish it to the users.

I want them to be free changing formatting, updating data and using the analytics buttons etc in the pivot table
but I don't want them to mess around with my work in power pivot window and see the source of data and the connections I've made.
How can I do this?

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 0):

Unless you use SharePoint, which offers document level security your Power BI workbook is totally without security.

If someone can open your workbook, they can view everything in your Power Pivot window.